# How to downgrade magento enterprise to community?

Tags: magento2.2

I want to migrate magento enterprise 2.2.7 to community 2.2.7, so anyone have steps for that.

I used this link but its not sufficient.
Link >> https://blog.magepsycho.com/migrate-downgrade-magento-2-from-enterprise-to-community-edition/

Comment: why its not sufficient?

Comment: because its not showing related to db changes , its only showing vendor changes.

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade?

Comment: Because i am not using the features of EE now so why should pay for EE.

Comment: Migrating is not an easy thing if you have custom modules and want to preserve data.  
You should mention what kind of issues you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

just export data and import to your new community store?? there are lots of extensions that offer full set of export profiles.

if you are looking for 100% data migration then no, it won't happen.

following the path: removing tables and modules from Commerce down to Community is not a good solution.

install new community version.